# How to query association after successful db.Save()

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am working with Gorm and Graphql. I hadn't run into problems querying data until I tried to connect two existing items using their `foreignkey` relationships. Here are my two models:

```
type Report struct {
    db.Base
    OwnerID         string
    Patient         patients.Patient `gorm:"association_name:Patient;"`
    PatientID       string
}
type Patient struct {
    db.Base
    ReportID   string
}
```

I have a function to save the relationship to the database:

```
func (s *Store) AddPatientToReport(ctx context.Context, id string, patient *patients.Patient) (*Report, error) {

    // check against user using context

    report, err := s.Report(ctx, id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("Could not find report.")
        return nil, err
    }

    report.PatientID = patient.ID

    if err := s.db.Save(&report).Association("Patient").Append(patient).Error; err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Error("add patient failed")
        return nil, err
    }

    return report, nil
}
```

After the above function I can query the `Report` and see the `patient_id`. I can also query the `Patient` and see the `report_id`. But the following query to get the whole `Patient` from the `Report` just returns empty.

```
query {
  report(id: "report_id") {
   id
   patientID // this will return the correct patient_id
   patient {
     id // this field always comes back as an empty string
   }
  }
}
```

Here is how the DB is setup:

```
// NewConn creates a new database connection
func NewConn(cc ConnConf) (*Conn, error) {
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", cc.getCtxStr())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Models are loaded from each package. Patients is created before Reports.
    if err := db.AutoMigrate(Models...).Error; err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    db.LogMode(cc.Logger)

    return &Conn{db}, err
}
```

I can't figure out how to get the whole `patient` back. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as it turns out I just needed to ask and then I'd figure it out on my own a few minutes later.

I'd read about `Preload()` in the Gorm docs, but didn't know where to implement it. I first tried when the DB fired up thinking it would load the associations. But I really needed to use `Preload()` as I run the query.

```
result := &Report{}
if err = s.db.Preload("Patient").Where(&query).First(&result).Error; err != nil {
  log.WithField("id", id).WithError(err).
    Error("could not find report")
    return nil, err
}
```

Now, the graphql query:

```
query {
  report(id: "some_id") {
    id
    patient {
      id // now it returns the id
      birthyear // now it returns other fields, too
      ...
    }
  }
}
```